# Is there a way to adjust the cursor blink rate in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to adjust the cursor blink rate in Visual Studio 2015? For example, in Notepad++ there is this window where I can adjust the blink rate:

[image: Notepad++ cursor blink]

Thank you

Comment: You might want to try cursor phasing instead of blinking, though the rate stays the same. "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase"

Comment: You can select option "editor.cursorBlinking": "solid" to avoid complete blinking

Answer (score 13):

Its pretty simple and easy
Go to file--->preferences---->settings
Select search item as "**cursor**"
In the results section. Choose cursor blinking to "**solid**"
Here you go problem solved.
[image]

Comment: This question is about Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio gets the cursor settings from your OS settings. You can stop the cursor from blinking by changing the cursor blink rate to "none".

### Windows XP/7/8/8.1

1. Go to Control Panel.
2. Click on the Keyboard item.
3. Under "Change blink rate" move the slider to "none" position.

[image: Windows 7: change cursor blink rate]

### Windows 10

Due to the discontinuation of the Control Panel in Windows 10, and the absence of corresponding option in the new Settings app, the easiest way to bring up the Keyboard Properties window is to run the following command from the Run prompt.

`control keyboard`

The same command can be used in previous Windows versions if you find this method easier.

**Visual Studio Code:** Note that this does not work with Visual Studio Code per version 1.22.2, because unlike Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code has its own controls for displaying and animating the cursor.

Comment: Digging in old posts here, but I think this is important for everyone choosing this option.
This causes a bug in all recent Windows versions that will let the notification flashes in the taskbar not go away at all.

This is referenced [here in reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/4qlgqp/taskbar_icons_stay_highlighted_orange_forever/)